# How to block messages from write?

Tags: ssh, scripting, write

I have an ssh account on a server. Someone is spamming me with `write` messages. So I can't run any command in an interactive login. Is there anyway I can prevent them from sending me write messages or any way I could just have a session without incoming write messages and do my things? I think they are just sending write messages to my usernames to whatever terminal I login with (pts/1 2 3 4 and so on) I don't want to contact the system admin for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man 1 write`:

> You can prevent people (other than the superuser) from writing to you
>          with the mesg(1) command.  Some commands, for example nroff(1) and
>          pr(1), may automatically disallow writing, so that the output they
>          produce isn't overwritten

From `man 1 mesg`:

> mesg [option] [n|y]

Therefore, running `mesg n` should disable this.