# Capture incoming terminal messages (write/mesg)

Tags: terminal, users, write

`write` allows sending messages to connected users terminal.

```
$ echo "hello budy" | write budy
```

This can become quite annoying when messages interfere with a terminal operation. A drastic solution consists in [blocking all incoming messages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413029/how-to-block-messages-from-write).

Is there an intermediate solution where messages would be dumped to a file without interfering with the terminal?

Comment: "_Is there an intermediate solution where messages would be dumped to a file without interfering with the terminal?_" - yes, it's called email

Comment: haha, thanks :'D but when working on a shared machine, some users may use `write` properly, while some other may use it to spam other users… And currently I see no other alternative than switching the whole feature off.

Answer (score 0):

You might be laughing at roaima's comment, but I fully concur with him.

Spammers put aside, even if someone tries to `write` you something with good intent, the message might interrupt your workflow and corrupt your display (as you said in the original post), or might even go completely unnoticed (e.g. if a utility you're running is producing lots of output, or if you're scrolling in your text editor etc.) (the sender won't know either that you missed the message).

`write`/`mesg` are leftovers from almost 50 years ago, reflecting the state-of-the-art user experience of those times. In my opinion they have no place in today's world, vendors should stop shipping those tools (i.e. block the possibility to write to someone else's tty).

Disable messaging to your terminal, and ask your friends to reach out to you via some other channel. Email, IM/chat software, phone, SMS, you name it. (I do mean it seriously, not sarcastically.)

Now, technically, it would be possible to write an utility that grabs a tty line, sets its permissions to allow messages, registers an utmp record, and then whenever it receives a message it dumps it to a file. I'm not aware of any such utility existing, but it shouldn't be hard to write one. Allegedly (as I've once heard, I haven't verified it) there used to be a KDE utility that did this and then presented the message as a graphical popup.

---

On a side note:

Your question talks about "connected users", so I assume that in your use case people ssh to some server (maybe at a uni campus or so). A similarly interesting question is `mesg`/`write` in graphical sessions and graphical terminal emulators.

For `mesg`/`write` to work, an `utmp` record needs to be registered. However, `utmp` is supposed to contain *login* information, and the terminal emulator is *not* the place where you *log in* to the system.

Many terminal emulators do perform `utmp` logging, while many others don't. I guess the world is shifting towards fewer and fewer doing so, because there were many new terminal emulators appearing recently, and I doubt that they add this old feature. Also, `gnome-terminal` [removed utmp logging](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046) about 7 years ago (over there you can read more arguments pro and con, including my opinion elaborated, in case you're interested).

Comment: Thanks. However, other channel of communication may simply not even exist if the only thing we have is a username on a shared machine. I believe they are still valid use cases of the 50 years old leftovers that are `write` and `mesg`. I'll have a look at utmp login meaning. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I did have such an utility (actually inspired by the one that KDE had at the time): https://git.nullroute.lt/cgit/hacks/wallnotify.git/ I have not touched it in around a decade so I'm not sure if it still works.